# In DataFrame.withColumn, how can I use the column's value as a condition for the second parameter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

If I have a DataFrame called df that looks like:

```
+---+---+
| a1+ a2|
+---+---+
|foo|bar|
|N/A|baz|
+---+---+
```

I would expect from:

```scala
val df2 = df.withColumn("a1", when($"a1" == "N/A", $"a2))
```

that df2 would look like:

```
+---+---+
| a1+ a2|
+---+---+
|foo|bar|
|baz|baz|
+---+---+
```

but instead I get:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

So it sounds like I need a method of Column that produces its value within a DataFrame's withColumn method.

Any such thing, or other approach to conditionally populate the replacement parameter of withColumn by the current column's value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `===` instead of `==`:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("a1", when($"a1" === "N/A", $"a2").otherwise($"a1"))
// df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a1: string, a2: string]

df2.show
+---+---+
| a1| a2|
+---+---+
|foo|bar|
|baz|baz|
+---+---+
```

Comment: I had a similar question, but instead on just one value "N/A", i wanna check it against a list of values, is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `===` not `==`:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("foo", "bar"), ("N/A", "baz")).toDF("a1", "a2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a1: string, a2: string]

scala> df.show
+---+---+
| a1| a2|
+---+---+
|foo|bar|
|N/A|baz|
+---+---+

scala> df.withColumn("a1", when($"a1" === "N/A", $"a2").otherwise($"a1")).show
+---+---+
| a1| a2|
+---+---+
|foo|bar|
|baz|baz|
+---+---+
```

Comment: @psidom beat you to it by 3 seconds... :O

Comment: @TzachZohar just shows that I should always have my Spark REPL running, that startup time could have made all the difference!

Comment: Awesome thanks to you both - bonus question then, how come === null doesn't seem to work?

Comment: `"null"` vs `null`? Hard to say w/o an example (preferably in its own post). There is also [`isNull`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@isNull:org.apache.spark.sql.Column)